# Creating package functions with the same name as existing package

Tags: r, dplyr, package, tidyverse, devtools

As a big proponent of the dplyr grammar, I have created a package that can be used to process a class often used in research (summarizedExperiment, or se) with similar syntax. (package name cleanse).

I have for instance defined a new `filter` function called `filter.SummarizedExperiment` that takes a se as its first argument and defined a dispatch function as `filter <- function(se, axis, ...){UseMethod("filter")}`.

This works as expected, but after loading the cleanse package, the dplyr equivalent functions are masked, and filtering data frames does not work anymore.

Is there a way I can *adjust my package so the original data frame version of dplyr can still be used* and the dispatch will automatically use either the dplyr or cleanse version depending on whether its first argument is a data frame or a SummarizedExperiment? What would be the best approach to this?

PS1: I am aware of the solution of using explicit namespace, i.e. using dplyr::filter, but would like a solution where dispatch takes place automatically based on the class.
PS2: dplyr is a dependency of cleanse, so all users will have dplyr installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dplyr already defines a generic for `filter` so just define your own method.  Here we return the string `se` when invoking `filter` on an `se` object so replace the body appropriately in `filter.se` :

```
library(dplyr)
filter.se <- function(x, ...) "se"
filter.default <- filter.ts <- stats::filter
```

dplyr's `filter` clobbers base R's filter and the last line above, which is optional, fixes that but if you don't use it then you will have to use `stats::filter` whenever you want to use base `filter`.

Test it out with:

```
filter(BOD, Time < 5)
filter(1:5, 3)
filter(structure(1, class = "se"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your suggestion. This works if I first load dplyr, but when loading only cleanse, the dispatch of an se fails and stats::filter is called instead of cleanse::filter. In line with this, my documentation examples using filter fail when running the error check for the package. Is there a solution so filter is correctly dispatched when only cleanse is loaded?

Comment: The question stated that dplyr is loaded and the answer clearly shows that library has been run. . If the question is mistaken and dplyr is not loaded then the generic will not be present and you will have to define the generic yourself.  If it still does not work some things to try are to put dplyr in Depends: and/or define filter.data.frame to invoke dplyr's version.